# When are (weak) homotopy equivalence testable on open covers?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190984/weak-equivalence-testable-on-invariant-open-covers) question on math.stackexchange, but did not get an answer.

Let $f\colon X\rightarrow X'$ be a continuous map between two spaces $X,X'$, which might be arbitrary wild, especially I don't want to work in any convenient category of topological spaces. Let $X=U\cup V$ and $X'=U'\cup V'$ be open covers such that $f(U)\subseteq U'$ and $f(V)\subseteq V'$ holds.

Consider the following claim.

> If the three restrictions $f\colon U\rightarrow V$, $f\colon V\rightarrow V'$ and $f\colon U\cap U'\rightarrow V\cap V'$ are weak homotopy equivalences, then so is $f\colon X\rightarrow X'$.

1. Is this claim true in general? If not, are there mild assumptions on $X$, $X'$ or $X$ and $X'$, such that the claim holds, e.g. does the claim hold if $X$ and $X'$ are Hausdorff spaces?
2. What about the corresponding claim with homotopy equivalences instead of weak equivalences?

Comment: @RonnieBrown: Is this related to your work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For weak homotopy equivalences this holds always (Theorem 6.7.9 in tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology*).

For homotopy equivalences this holds provided the open covers are numerable (Theorem 4.2.7 loc. cit.)

Comment: The original post says that U and V are open, and in this case the pushout is always a homotopy pushout, regardless of numerability.

Comment: @Dmitri That's true for homotopy pushouts with respect to weak homotopy equivalences and that's what the first part of my answer says. The notion of a homotopy pushout with respect to homotopy equivalences is stronger and here you need numerability.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the clarification.  I must say that the usage of “homotopy pushout” in tom Dieck's book without any additional clarifiers to mean “homotopy pushout in topological spaces equipped with homotopy equivalences” is rather confusing.

Comment: That terminology is indeed non-standard, but it is unfair to say that it is not clarified. The definition is given right above Proposition 4.2.3 which I originally cited. (Tom later changed this to 4.2.7 which does answer his question more directly.)

Comment: Yes, tom Dieck does define it, but “clarifier” really means “adjective” above, i.e., somebody who just reads this particular statement may be misled if he doesn't also read the definition above.

Comment: The way I see it, readers who skip definitions can only blame themselves.

Comment: But not for a completely standard notion such as a homotopy colimit.  Should the reader also be blamed if the author uses a nonstandard definition of a topological space (say)?

Comment: The notion of a homotopy colimit clearly depends both on the category and the chosen class of weak equivalences. Tom Diecks definition of homotopy colimits is in the same style as the usual textbook definition of (co)homology theories, without the weak equivalence axiom, so that one can include things like Cech cohomology.

Answer (score 5):

Let me offer sufficient conditions in both cases. They follow from the existence of the following two left proper model structures on the category of topological spaces, and the well-known gluing lemma holding in such categories:

1. Weak equivalences = weak homotopy equivalences, cofibrations = retracts of relative CW-complexes, fibrations = Serre fibrations [Quillen].
2. Weak equivalences = homotopy equivalences, cofibrations = closed immersion with the homotopy extension property, fibrations = Hurewicz fibrations [Strom].

In either case, it is enough to assume that $U\cap V$ contains a deformation retract $A\subset U\cap V$ such that $A\subset U$ or $A\subset V$ is a cofibration, and similarly fo $X'$.

Answer (score 2):

The claim about weak equivalences follows as soon as one proves that the cocartesian squares generated by U←U∩V→V and U'←U'∩V'→V' are also homotopy cocartesian.

To this end one can use Lurie's Seifert-van Kampen theorem (Theorem A.3.1 in Higher Algebra) to establish that these squares are always homotopy cocartesian: in Lurie's
notation, take C={1←0→2} and the functor χ sends C to {U←U∩V→V}.
The fact that {U,V} is an open cover of X establishes
the required property (*).

(Of course, this particular fact had been established
long before Lurie's book came out and can be found in many older, less accessible references.)

Comment: Do you mean, for example, the work of @RonnieBrown?

Comment: @SeanTilson: If you are referring to the last paragraph, the relevant statement is almost certainly much older and can probably be dug out from the papers by Borsuk, Leray, Weil, and McCord.